# Using adapter for listview

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have an arraylist that needs to be updated using the adpater. I dont have any textviews for it. Here is my code -

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private ArrayList<MyClass> favouriteMessageList;

    private MyAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList list) {
        favouriteMessageList = list;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        MyClass favouriteMessage =  favouriteMessageList.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messaging_favorites_layout, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<MyClass> data) {
        favouriteMessageList = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

The `setData` method will receive an arraylist and I need to populate the view with my Arraylist. I am using a `viewHolder`. How do I achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you have not TextViews? And what are you trying to get?

Comment: How to use textview in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private ArrayList<MyClass> favouriteMessageList;

    private MyAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList list) {
        favouriteMessageList = list;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        MyClass favouriteMessage = favouriteMessageList.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messaging_favorites_layout, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //Update Your Views Here
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (favouriteMessageList != null) return favouriteMessageList.size();
        return 0;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<MyClass> data) {
        favouriteMessageList = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```